# Jquery Button's Onclick Function Not Redirecting

Tags: jquery, html, button, onclick

I've created a function that creates a button and adds several attributes to it. My problem is that when I try to add an 'onClick' attribute to it, nothing happens when I click the button. My files are below

```
function GoToForm() {
      window.location = 'SurveyForm.htm';
}

function MakeButton() {
    var btn=$("<button/>");
        btn.text('view/Edit ');
        btn.val=20
        btn.id=3
        btn.onclick="GoToForm()";
                     $('#report_area').append(btn);
}
```

Html File

```
<html>
    ....
       ....
         <p id="report_area"></p>
       ....
    ....
</html>
```

I'm actually appending the button to an area on my html page. For now, let's just say I call this 'MakeButton()' function when the page loads or document becomes ready or whatever. With my button there, it's clickable, but it doesn't redirect me to my other page, SurveyForm.htm.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var btn = document.createElement('button')
        $(btn).text('view/Edit ');
        $(btn).val=20
        $(btn).id=3
        $(btn).click(function(){
            window.location = 'SurveyForm.htm';
        });
       $('#report_area').append(btn);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I feel so slow sometimes, how fast some of you all come up with this stuff. I guess if I needed to pass anything to that page, I would do it inside that function/area as well, correct?